# Spring Boot ModelAndView controller can't find html view under templates except adding Thymeleaf dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

New to Spring/Spring Boot, having following problem..

I created a ModelAndView controller below:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
// import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
// import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TodoController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TodoController.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        logger.info("cassie Request to GET index");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("hello");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

And my `hello.html` is under `/src/main/resources/templates`, but Spring Boot can't locate the view, and throw a Whitelabel Error...
However, after I added `Thymeleaf` dependency, it magically worked. I looked it up that template engine like Thymeleaf is not necessary for Spring Boot, so can someone help me understand why my Spring Boot could not locate my html file? Thanks!

Tried to isolate to see which part of my code went wrong. Seems like it's something to do with the `ModelAndView` object which somehow makes Spring Boot unable to render the template (if `hello()` method returns a String, it worked perfectly fine.

Also, tried to add below properties, but still didn't find the html:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: classpath:/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```